# I am getting error when opening eclipse IDE -could not open 'c:\Program files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When I open Eclipse
 I get below Error could not open 'c:\Program files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

[image]

Two days before it was working , I just downloaded android studio and installed and after that my eclipse IDE is not working

Comment: Does that file actually exist?

Comment: no its not there, i can see only ext folder in this path -C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib

Answer (score 0):

Please check your eclipse.ini file and update to what version of java you have. In my case I have java 1.8 and this is what it's look like

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: Also have you upgraded java ? If yes you might need to do manual clean up from C:\Windows\System32 as default installation also copied java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to mentioned location. Many times uninstallation of JRE didn't go well.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the java and restarted the machine now its working fine